# How do you get to 'swing' in java in netbeans ide?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans

How do you get to 'swing' in java in netbeans ide?  Im trying to switch from eclipse.  i was in it but i cannot navigate the page and im in the 'gui code' layout currently but i need to get back into the gui to add buttions

Comment: Do you mean the form editor? Have you tried looking at something like [Designing a Swing GUI in NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html)?

Comment: yes but in the editor i am trying to get back to the view page of what i am designing in my gui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at the top of the window you'll see 3 'tab' buttons.  one says  source another design and another history.  you car currently in the source one you need to go into the display one.  The question is confusing but I think that is what you are asking.